Assistance Needed in Replicating Charge Density Difference Plot for g-C3N4/Pt System
I'm currently facing a challenge in replicating the charge density difference (CDD) plot showcased in Figure 7(b) of this paper. Specifically, I'm attempting to reproduce the CDD plot for the transition state of CO oxidation within the g-C3N4/Pt system. 

Despite having successfully conducted similar calculations in the past using the same INCAR as given below, I'm encountering difficulties this time around.
LSCALAPACK= .FALSE.
NPAR= 1 
LPLANE= .TRUE. 
NSIM= 1 

ISYM= 2 
ENCUT= 500 
PREC= Accurate 
NELMIN=10 
NGX= 54 
NGY= 54 
NGZ= 146 
ADDGRID=.TRUE. 
EDIFF= 0.1E-05 

NSW= 0 
IBRION= -1 
ISPIN= 2

ALGO= FAST 
ISMEAR= 1 
SIGMA= 0.1 

LREAL= .FALSE.
LASPH= .TRUE. 
LORBIT= 10
IDIPOL= 3  
LDIPOL= .TRUE.
LCHARG= .TRUE.
LAECHG= .TRUE.
LWAVE= .FALSE. 

IVDW= 12
VDW_RADIUS=50.2
VDW_CNRADIUS=20.0 
VDW_S8 = 0.7875
VDW_A1 = 0.4289
VDW_A2 = 4.4407

I haven't been able to detect any charge density difference on the reactants (below left). Even adjusting the isosurface value yielded inconsistent outcomes (below right).

In my attempt to troubleshoot, I increased the NGX, NGY, and NGZ values by 50% of their default values and re-ran the calculations. However, upon visualization of the CDD using VESTA, the default isosurface of 0.09 failed to reveal any noticeable differential charge on the reactants. Only by reducing the isosurface value to 0.0004 did I observe differential charges around CO and O, albeit with an unexpected behavior from C3N4.
Notably, I utilized DFT-D3 vdW correction, while the authors of the paper employed the optPBE-vdW functional. Additionally, there may be slight disparities in the geometry of the transition state. However, I'm hesitant to attribute these differences as the sole reason for the absence of observable differential charges.

Your insights and assistance in helping me replicate this plot for my future research would be immensely appreciated.
Thank you kindly for your time and support.

+1 Are you confident that you have followed the right steps in getting the charge density difference?

Yes, I used the above INCAR file for the SCF calculations on the transition state coordinates. Then the same was repeated : (i) by removing the coordinates of C3N4 from the TS and (ii) with only C3N4 coordinates. The CHGCARs obtained from the later two were subtracted from the CHGCAR of the TS.

In the first step of the calculation, which atoms were allowed to relax before running the SCF calculation? cause maybe if the structure at the bottom and the CO and O are kept constant then eventually when you subtract the CHGCARs, the charges over there will cancel out

None of the atoms were relaxed. These are single point calculations keeping NSW=0 in INCAR.

I think I found the reason. The vacuum slab needed to be increased in my case!
